# Show only top portion of image in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, uiimageview

I need to align a UIImageView in a way that only top portion of the image is shown.

Original Image:-

[image: Screen Shot]

I achieved Image from below Code:-

[image: Screen Shot]

Code:-

```
Image("ImageDemo")
  .resizable()
  .scaledToFill()
  .frame(height: 120, alignment: .center)
  .clipped()
  .cornerRadius(20, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
  .padding(.bottom)
```

Can someone please explain to me how to show image with top portion only, I've tried to implement by above but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not really clear what do you try to achieve, because provided code (and 2nd screenshot shows this) really cut top of image 120pt height. So, what's wrong?

Comment: See first image top of coffee cup brown colour and see second image which brown colour cut from the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `alignment: .top` it will fix your issue.

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

            Image("Your Image Here!")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .frame(height: 120, alignment: .top) //  <<: Here
                .clipped()
                .padding()

    }
}
```

---